# JQuery click only registers first click and not subsequent clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, click, haml

I have a button group of three buttons. The relevant haml code is:

```
   .btn-group#refresh-buttons
              %button.btn.btn-default#refresh-5-sec 5 sec
              %button.btn.btn-default#refresh-30-sec 30 sec
              %button.btn.btn-default#refresh-60-sec 60 sec
```

I'm trying to build an adjustable refresh-rate feature. The first click registers and sets the refresh rate correctly (I inspected the event object) but subsequent clicks on any button thereafter do not register, they do not create an event object. My JS code is below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var intervalId = window.setInterval(function(){
     $('.container').load('/dashboard/index .container');
  }, 60000);
  console.log(intervalId);

  $("#refresh-buttons").on("click", "button", function(event) {
    if(event.target.id === "refresh-5-sec") {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
      setInterval(function(){
         $('.container').load('/dashboard/index .container');
      }, 5000);
    }
    else if(event.target.id === "refresh-30-sec") {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
      setInterval(function(){
         $('.container').load('/dashboard/index .container');
      }, 10000);
    }
    else if(event.target.id === "refresh-60-sec") {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
      setInterval(function(){
         $('.container').load('/dashboard/index .container');
      }, 15000);
    }
  });
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: And `#refresh-buttons` is of course ***not*** inside the `.container` element ?

Comment: Actually yes the #refresh-buttons were in the `.container` element, so that seems obviously wrong now that you've pointed that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned, if the `.container` element contains the button group then you need to use event delegation.  There was another issue in the code, however.  You were not setting `intervalId` each time you changed the refresh rate, so you would end up with multiple instances of `setInterval()` running.

I also tidied up a little as there was some code duplication going on...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var intervalId = window.setInterval(function(){
        $('.container').load('/dashboard/index .container');
    }, 60000);
    console.log(intervalId);

    $(document).on("click", "#refresh-buttons button", function(event) {

        var interval = 0;

        switch(event.target.id) {
            case: "refresh-5-sec" {
                interval = 5000;
                break;
            }
            case: "refresh-30-sec" {
                interval = 30000;
                break;
            }
            case: "refresh-60-sec" {
                interval = 60000;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (interval != 0)
        {
            clearInterval(intervalId);
            intervalId = setInterval(function(){
                $('.container').load('/dashboard/index .container');
            }, interval);
        }
    }
});
```

You should really change the click event handler so it's not attached to `document`.  That example will work no matter how you change your page, but it's advisable to use the closest selector to the buttons as possible, that does not change when you do a `load()`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been banging my head against this little feature all day. I guess the key distinctions to take away are selecting the right elements to filter on and realizing that elements that are loaded overwrite any previously existing handlers. Again thanks, this was awesome. I really like your use of whitespace, alot easier on the eyes.

Comment: Thanks for the click event handler tip, as well, I've narrowed the scope of the handler to as close as I can get to button-group and the scope of the load to just the part of the page that needs to be replaced. Again, thanks for you advice.

Comment: No problem mate - I'm glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 2):

As @adeneo points out in his comment above, the `#refresh-buttons` element can't be inside the `.container` element, because you overwrite it on `load()` and therefore remove the event handler you attached.

If the `#refresh-buttons` element is inside the `.container` element, you have to use a delegate on a non-changing parent element, like this:

```
$(".container").on("click", "#refresh-buttons button", function(event) {...});
```